# Problem with decorations in a small TikZ picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath, decorations

When working on yesterday's update on my answer to [the december challenge](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280771/december-challenge-create-an-advent-calendar/280799#280799) (a dcorated tree), I encountered a problem: if I choose the picture's dimensions to small, then it fails with

> Dimension too large.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\XMasPic}[5]%
% x pos, ypos, width, height, draw commands
{   \begin{scope}[shift={(#1,#2)}, x={(#3,0)}, y={(0,#4)}]
        \fill[gray!5] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
        \draw[clip] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
        #5
        \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \end{scope}
}

\newcommand{\DecoratedTree}[4]%
{ \XMasPic{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}%
    {   \fill[inner color=blue!40!black, outer color=blue!10!black] (0.02,0.02) rectangle (0.98,0.98);
        \xdef\CuCo{0}
        \draw
        [   yellow,
            bend left=10,
            decoration=
            {   markings,
                mark=between positions 0.01 and 1 step 0.02 with
                {   
                    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\C}{mod(\CuCo,3)}
                    \fill[inner color=\ifcase\C red\or blue\or yellow\fi, outer color=transparent, opacity=0.2] (0,0) circle (0.015);
                    \fill[inner color=\ifcase\C red\or blue\or yellow\fi, outer color=\ifcase\C red!50\or blue!50\or yellow!50\fi] (0,0) circle (0.005);
                    \pgfmathparse{\CuCo+1}
                    \xdef\CuCo{\pgfmathresult}
                }
            },
            postaction={decorate}] (0.61,0.21) to (0.40,0.265) (0.585,0.325) to (0.43,0.38) (0.56,0.44) to (0.45,0.50) (0.55,0.55) to (0.46,0.61) (0.53,0.665) to (0.475,0.72);
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    %\DecoratedTree{4}{0}{3.2}{3.2} % fails; 
    \DecoratedTree{0}{0}{3.3}{3.3}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Expected Output

[image]

The `\XMasPic` is a wrapper that scales the image to the desired dimensions (width `#3` and height `#4`) and internally provides a coordinate scaling so that all coordinates can be expressed as values bewtween 0 and 1 (see Caramdir's answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz?lq=1))

This error appears to occur due to the small increment in the decoration:

`mark=between positions 0.01 and 1 step`**`0.02`**`with {...}`

I suspect that the step `0.02` is so small that *pgfmath* rounds it to zero and therefore never finishes.

Can anyone confirm this is the reason for this error, and ideally recommend a way to get around it?

Comment: I asked a general question about this [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281649/how-can-i-minimise-errors-arising-from-tikz-pictures-involving-too-large-dimensi).

Comment: Not sure but can you say `\begin{scope}[shift={(#1,#2)}, xscale=#3, yscale=#4]` rather than setting `x` and `y`? That is, I'm not sure if this is equivalent or not.

Comment: [I guess it is not equivalent: the y seems too squished.]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the error cannot be reproduced anymore.